# Critério para sincronização de dados

Tags: requisitos

Bom dia, queria dicas para critério de sincronização de dados, vamos ao cenário.

Seguinte tenho um sistema com um administrativo onde cadastra produtos, clientes, usuários, libera permissões, unidades de produto, estoque de produto entre outros n dados.

Tenho o PDV (Ponto de venda) preciso que ele funcione sem rede mas ai o pensamento que tive inicialmente .

Sincronizo todos dados para o pdv de tempos em tempos..

mas pera ai e se eu tiver 300mil produtos , vou sincronizar todos de 5 em 5 segundos? jamais..

então pensei em controlar pela ultima dada de alteração (atributo alteradoEm)
toda vez que salvo um produto ou qualquer outro dado que é sincronizado com o pdv eu jogo a data e hora atual no atributo alteradoEm é com base na ultimaSincronizacao

ultimaSincronizacao < alteradoEm ----- sincronizo tudo

salvo a data da ultimaSincronizacao

e bingo! melhorou ne?

mas... e se o usuário voltar a data do pc e salvar um produto .. hahaha ferrou minha vida =/

ai e onde quero saber que critérios usar para fazer uma sincronização de dados..

aqui uso sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

#### Algoritmo geral

Tenha um campo `versaoLocal` e um campo `versaoRemota`. Teste se eles são diferentes. Se diferentes, precisa atualizar, se não, bom estão iguais, nada a fazer.

O algoritmo específico é:

1. Num dado local você atualiza somente o campo `versaoLocal`.
2. Levanta todos os registros com `versaoLocal` != `versaoRemota`.
3. Cada um, roda o processo de atualização
4. Cada um, *usando os dados em memória*, faz `versaoLocal = versaoRemota` (se download), ou `versaoRemota = versaoLocal`, se upload.

#### Com timestamps

Testar por diferença resolve a questão relógios errados, timezones, horário de verão...

Ainda corre o risco de coincidir de gerar um timestamp local igual a um timestamp remoto. Risco baixo, mas existe. Se usar timestamps, coloque o máximo de decimais de milissegundos disponível.

#### rowversion, UUID,  ou *triggers*

Em vez confiar em data/hora, utilizar outra fonte de versionamento. Alguns bancos fornecem campos tipo `rowversion`, que garantem *para aquela instância de banco* sempre terá um número novo, sem repetições, a cada UPDATE. Tem no [SQL Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms182776(v=sql.120).aspx).

Na falta disso utilizar funcionalidade de [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) que a linguagem forneça.

Como mais uma alternativa, triggers no banco, que em qualquer UPDATE incremente o número `versaoLocal` daquele registro.

Novamente, basta testar por diferença para saber quando atualizar.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, seguinte sua ideia é boa mas resolvemos de outra maneira aqui na empresa,

fizemos assim, vamos ter uma tabela (pendentes_sync) (int referencia, int terminaloffline, int tipoSincronizado)

referencia e o ID do objeto que quero sincronizar
terimaloffline é o ID do terminaloffile (explico abaixo)
tipoSincronizado dentro do sistema ele sera um enum.. que diz o tipo de dado que esta sendo sincronizado, exemplo se for 1.. é um Produto , se for 3 é um usuário, se for 7 é unidade_produto e por ai vai..

Terminal Offline oque é? 
Bom terminal offline (vou dar como exemplo um pdv)

você esta no supermercado e esta iniciando a implantação do sistema você instala o administrativo e o os pdvs, 
para iniciar um pdv você deve ter um Terminal Offline.. se não tiver o pdv simplesmente não irá sair da tela de seleção do terminal offline..

Cadastro do terminal offline..
poderia ter uma ECF já cadastrada e vinculada ao pdv se tu souber a porta que sera pode colocar aqui.. se não souber ok da nada não seleciona no pdv..
uma descrição para o terminal offline,
tempo de sincronização,
é um atributo para amarrar o pdv em determinado terminal offline,

ao cadastrar o terminal offline,
você simplesmente seleciona ele no pdv e bingo! uma pré-configuração esta pronta.. 
supondo que você fez o cadastro e errou a porta da ECF o pdv.. não irá conectar e sim mostrar uma opção para colocar a porta da ecf correta.. você coloca (o sincronizador irá enviar a porta para o cadastro no servidor)

básicamente e isso o terminal offline..

vamos a parte da sincronização

pendentes_sync a tabela que lhe informei acima...

quando eu cadastrar um produto vou ter que inserir 
a referencia (id do produto), idterminalOffline (se tiver dois terminais tera que ter duas inserções uma para cada..) , tipoSincronizado  (um indicador de que você está sincronizando um produto)

o mesmo processo para alterar o produto..

bom ai oque acontece.. se tiver dois terminais.. terá duas inserções uma para cada terminal

quando o pdv (terminal) fizer a sincronização ele sera baseada nessa tabela.. 
pegara os dados dela.. vai ver que existe produto pendente para sincronizar..
pega o id dele busca ele e atualiza/insere o produto no pdv.. e deleta o registro da tabela pendentes_sync que se referia a essa atualização..

e basicamente isso oque pensamos

se tiver alguma ideia onde podemos melhorará e bem vinda =)